# React useState usage count

Tags: reactjs

```
const CustomerListView = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(); 
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState(); 
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]); 
  const [addUser, setAddUser] = useState(); 
  const [editUser, setEditUser] = useState(); 
  const [inputRead, setInputRead] = useState(); 
  const [selClear, setSelClear] = useState(false); 

  const { data: userType } = useQuery(USR_TP_CD);

  return (
    <Page className={classes.root} title="Customers">
      <Container maxWidth={false}>
        <AdminUserBar
       
          setSelected={setSelected}
          setAddUser={setAddUser}
          setEditUser={setEditUser}
          setTableData={setTableData}
          setInputRead={setInputRead}
          setSelClear={setSelClear}
          
          userType={userType}
        />
        <Box mt={1}>
          <AdminUserTable
    
            setDetailData={setDetailData}
            setInputRead={setInputRead}
            setAddUser={setAddUser}
            setEditUser={setEditUser}
            //현재 값
            selected={selected}
            addUser={addUser}
            tableData={tableData}
            selClear={selClear}
            editUser={editUser}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box mt={1}>
          <AdminUserDetail
     
            setAddUser={setAddUser}
            setEditUser={setEditUser}
            //현재 값
            userType={userType}
            detailData={detailData}
            inputRead={inputRead}
          />
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default CustomerListView;

const Toolbar = ({
  className,
  setTableData: postTableData,
  setSelected,
  setAddUser,
  setEditUser,
  userType,
  setSelClear,
  setInputRead,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm(); // 인풋 폼 전송시 인풋 값 받는 함수 (react-hook-form 라이브러리)
  const [param, setParam] = useState(); // 유저 조회시 POST 보내는 값
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(''); // 유형 선택시 해당 값 상태
  const activeParam = { PG_CNT: 10, PG_IDX: 0 }; // 유저 조회시 POST 실행시 기본으로 param이랑 같이 보내야하는 값
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(ADMIN_USER, {
    returnPartialData: true,
    skip: param === undefined,
    variables: { param, ver: 'v1' }
  });
  const onClick = () => {
    setInputRead(false);
  };
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSelectValue(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log(param);
  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    datas => {
      setParam({ ...datas, ...activeParam, USR_TP_CD: selectValue }); //조회 인풋값은 받아와 조회함
      setSelClear(true); //조회시 true값을 테이블 컴포넌트로 보내 클릭한 셀 클리어
      setSelected([]); // 조회시 select 배열로 저장된 값을 빈배열로 초기화
      setAddUser(undefined); // 유저추가후 addUser데이터가 남아있어 조회시 유저가 추가됨. 그래서 undefined로 초기화
      setEditUser(undefined); // 유저추가후 editUser데이터가 남아있어 조회시 유저가 추가됨. 그래서 undefined로 초기화
    },
    [
      selectValue,
      setAddUser,
      setEditUser,
      setSelected,
      activeParam,
      setSelClear,
      refetch
    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    postTableData(data);
  }, [postTableData, data]);



function AdminUserDetail({
  setAddUser,
  detailData: userDetailData,
  className,
  inputRead,
  setEditUser,
  userType,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset, setValue } = useForm(); // 인풋 폼 데이터 라이브러리
  const [addWait, setAddWait] = useState(false); // 저장 전송시 true로 바뀐후 onSubmit 실행후 ADD 뮤테이션 실행
  const [editWait, setEditWait] = useState(false); // 저상 전송시 true로 바뀐후 onSubmit 실행후 EDIT 뮤테이션 실행
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState(); // Index컴포넌트에서 userDetailData받아 useEffect를 통해 디테일 정보받음
  const [postFormData, setPostFormData] = useState(); // 인풋값을 받아 ADD_USER 뮤테이션 POST
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(''); // 유형 선택시 해당 값 상태
  const [ReadState, setReadState] = useState(false); // 리셋 및 수정 클릭시 인풋 readOnly 해제

  useEffect(() => {
    setReadState(inputRead); // Bar 컴포넌트에서 조회시 false값 받아 읽기 전용으로 바꿈
    setDetailData(userDetailData); // 테이블 컴포넌트에서 유저 클릭시 데이터 받음
    setEditWait(inputRead); // Bar 컴포넌트에서 조회시 false값 받아 유저 수정 기다림 변경
    setAddWait(inputRead); //Bar 컴포넌트에서 조회시 false값 받아 유저 추가 기다림 변경
    if (detailData !== undefined) {
      // 테이블 컴포넌트에서 유저 데이터 받으면 해당 유저 데이터를 각 인풋 value 추가
      setValue('USR_ID', detailData?.USR_ID);
      setValue('USR_NM', detailData?.USR_NM);
      setValue('BLN_NM', detailData?.BLN_NM);
      setValue('HP', detailData?.HP);
      setValue('EML', detailData?.EML);
      setSelectValue(detailData?.USR_TP_CD);
    }
  }, [userDetailData, detailData, inputRead, userType, setValue]);
  //
  console.log(selectValue, postFormData);
  const [addMutation] = useMutation(ADD_USER, {
    variables: {
      user: postFormData,
      ver: 'v1'
    }
  });
  const [editMutation] = useMutation(EDI_USER, {
    variables: {
      user: postFormData,
      ver: 'v1'
    }
  });

  const handleChange = event => {
    setSelectValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const inputReset = () => {
    setReadState(true);
    setAddWait(true);
    setEditWait(false);
    setEditUser(undefined);
    reset();
  };
  const editClick = () => {
    if (detailData !== undefined) {
      setReadState(true);
      setEditWait(true);
      setAddWait(false);
      setAddUser(undefined);
    } else {
      toast.error(`✔ 수정을 원하는 유저를 클릭해주세요.`);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = async data => {
    setPostFormData(datas => ({ ...datas, ...data, USR_TP_CD: selectValue }));
    setReadState(false);

    if (addWait === true) {
      try {
        setAddUser({ ...data, USR_TP_CD: selectValue });
        await addMutation();

        setAddWait(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        setAddWait(false);
      }
    }
    if (editWait === true) {
      if (detailData?.USR_ID === data?.USR_ID) {
        try {
          setEditUser({ ...data, USR_TP_CD: selectValue });
          const datass = await editMutation();
          console.log(postFormData && postFormData);

          setEditWait(false);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          setEditWait(false);
        }
      } else {
        toast.error('선택한 유저 ID와 변경 ID가 동일하지 않습니다.');
      }
    }
  };
```

I am a new employee of the React Admin site project.
I have created a page that implements add, delete and modify functions using ag-grid.
But I wonder if the useState has been used too much to reduce readability.
if I can use the useState like this because it is my first time working on a project like this and I don't have a project that I can refer to the data.
Do you usually use this much useState? Or am I overusing it?

The useStates of the first component act as a bridge.

Comment: The question is opinion-based and so is offtopic on SO. It makes sense to keep multiple useState states because this allows to perform state updates and so rerenders independently. Otherwise they clutter the component, especially considering they you have to pass all those props. Use a common state object the same way as you would do in class component.

Comment: You said a good thing, but you mean it's okay to use multiple useStates?

Comment: It's ok if you know why you do this instead of using one useState. If you don't, this is likely an antipattern. The component suggests that it's so because it's cluttered with multiple state pieces for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the useReducer hook when I have many state updates one behind the other like this:

```
  const inputReset = () => {
    setReadState(true);
    setAddWait(true);
    setEditWait(false);
    setEditUser(undefined);
    reset();
  };
```

This will cause at least 5 component re render.